# Emit Rigid Bodies in a similar way to a particle system

Tags: particles, rigid-body-simulation

i'm trying to make a scene where icons are shot up out of a phone screen and im running into some issues with the icons. I tried using a particle sim and while this does shoot out of the phone in the correct way (Screenshot below), when using the particle sim i run into issue with the icons not colliding with each other and then also when they land on the floor they half clip through it. I have tried adding some Brownian force to the system to try to imitate them bumping into each other in mid air but they still do clip through each other. I tried enabling Size deflect to get them to land on the floor and not clip through but this didn't seem to work, it just made my icons float a few units above the floor and made the initial forces on the icons behave strangely. Finally i tried using the molecular addon but this didn't see, to work at all, enabling self collision made the icons shoot across the screen in all different directions and then, if i turned the damping up they just seems to stick to each other so i just gave up on that idea.

I now want to just try doing all of this with rigid bodies, so the question i now have is, how can i make multiple rigid bodies "emit" from a source with some sort of randomness (would i need to manually do this or can i have a seeded random emission like in a particle system) and then how would I add forces to these without having to key frame each individual icon to shoot at different times.

[image]

Comment: From what I know, particles can't interact in Blender (at least for the moment), so it looks like you need to use Rigid Body, as you say. Maybe you could create a kind of invisible funel to make them fall randomly?

Comment: do you mind using animation nodes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been done in Vers 2.77 and written for those with reasonable experience.  The Blend file is below.

[image]

Producing the coins -

Make one coin some reasonable distance above the table and at frame 1, give it Rigid Body Physics.
Set a keyframe for whatever physics settings, sliders, and tick-boxes you think you'll need.

Suggestions - Dynamic, Animated(?), Friction(?), Bouncing, Sensitivity->Margin,  and possibly damping sliders as well if you think they'll be needed.

Check the physics out, see if it's active.  It won't be right but that's not a problem at this stage.

.

Make a save of the Blend file at this point, plus a backup save (different filename) so you can come back to here if need be.

Reload the original file and produce as many coins as required using the Array Modifier.
All copies will inherit the 1st's properties and keyframes, including it's physics.  They should also be linked, meaning, changing keyframed settings in one will change them all.

The array is then 'Applied' so all coins are solid objects albeit still joined as one mesh.
The physics will probably act up but  leave that for now.

.

Next we have to separate the coins into separate objects with their individual Origin points.

Select the array, go into Edit mode --> Vertices.

Press A to select them all and press P --> Loose Parts.

Back in Object mode all coins will now be separate (Rigid Body) mesh but all will still be sharing the same Origin Point.

Select them all with one as the "Active" object and open the Tools panel (T), select -
'Set Origin --> Center of Mass'.   Each coin should then have it's own central Origin point.

Play the animation.   Chances are it won't be right.  Coins penetrating the ground, fidgeiting etc.

-=============-.

Managing all coins' physics universally -

If the above procedure was followed, all coins should be 'linked' so whatever keyframed changes you make to one will change them all.

If not linked do so to any single coin. (The active object)

PHYSICS NOTES -

Should the "Mesh/Convex Hull" setting need to be changed, that can't be keyframed but all can be changed with the one click by selecting all again (with an "Active Object").  Change the active object's setting to 'Mesh' (or whatever) and link again, choose 'Object to scene'.
That will re-link them all and with the new change(s) in place.

Alternatively, return to the backup saved file and change the setting in there, re-save it and redo the above steps.

Physics Settings -

For now a Sensitivity Margin of 0.002 should do.  It won't be right but that will be taken care of once we introduce a 'Deflector'.

-================-

The coins can be gathered and dragged inside the phone to 'float' well above it's base but still under the glass.  It won't matter if they're clipping each other.

At frame 20 or greater, select one coin and tick it's physics --> Dynamic box.  Keyframe that.

When played and the activation frame is reached the coins should begin to jump apart although probably not as hoped for.  To steer their trajectories so they launch vertically and dome-fashion, a shaped 'Deflector' plane is laid between the phone's base and the coins.

[image]

The deflector is a shaped Rigid Body plane with settings that force the coins to launch as required.

Adjust the Deflector's physics (and shape) so coins don't shoot down or through the phone's base or sides.  The ground's margin setting can also be keyframed for best launch results.

-==============-

The fidgets -

Most times in a scenario such as this no one single setting for the ground and 2nd deflector, (a cube placed over the phone) is going to work throughout so we change them with keyframes to make sure they do.

The phone itself is not a Rigid Body.  That's to ensure it won't interfere with the coins' launch.  Once the coins are on their way however, the original deflector is removed in the space of a single frame and a 2nd, an invisible Rigid Body cube the same size as the phone is moved directly over it (as though a cover) for the coins to land on.  This happens at frame 25.

Rigid Bodies can fidget when at rest because of they are constantly wanting to get away from each other and the object they're sitting on.  Their margin setting could be keyframed lower but that can lead to clipping or unwanted behavior.

Usually you can stop this by switching off their physics individually or as a group (untick the Dynamic box) and animate one or a few to continue on after if the instant  'freeze'  is noticeable.

In this case we have two groups of coins, those that end up on the table and those on the phone.
Both will (sort of) settle at different times so the original link will have to be broken and two new link-groups formed if we don't want to be adjusting & keyframing every single coin.

.

Firstly unlink all coins by selecting all and pressing 'U'.

Re-form two new linked-groups by playing the animation until the coins are sitting at their respective destinations.

[image]

Select the coins on the table and make one the 'Active Object', then link those.

Replay the animation to the frame you want them to remain stationary. (lose physics)

Select just one of those coins and untick the Dynamic box and keyframe that. (press i in the box)
All in that group should henceforth freeze at that frame.

Do the same with those that land on the phone.

When all is as desired, keyframe the coins to be invisible at frame 1 and visible at their launch frame +1.

-==================-

What's that invisible Rigid Body cube for ? -

Good question!  The phone deflector 'had attitude' and wouldn't work so a Rigid Body cube was dropped on it and after some mucking around it did work.  When attempting to remove the cube, the coins acted up!

.....

All objects have been blocked from selection in the Outliner to prevent inadvertent interference.
It takes very little to upset the physics engine.  To re-activate, simply click on the shaded arrow, or drag down from the first shaded arrow to activate them all.
You might have to do the same on the eye icons as well when they're shaded or keyframed off.  (eye icons for visibilty in the viewport and for rendering)

[image]

Comment: this is a good write up, but i actually figured out quite a simple way to do it using this addon that works in 3.0. its litterally one button click once you have the particle system you want, it converts it all to rigid bodies with their activiation keyframes. https://blenderartists.org/t/copy-particles-to-rigid-bodies/563269

Comment: Thanks for the comment Michael.  I kept away from particles because you said you were going for only RB's.  The add-on sounds good though.  I'm a bit of a stickler for using only a few add-ons and then those included with the version I'm using. (2.77) so I tend to be doing things the long way around.  It's good to hear you got it going, that's the objective after all.  Now if I can just get my mobile to emit REAL coins...